# How to make relationship between two models and update the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

It's me again but now I need some more help from you, I have some version of shopping cart and the whole idea is when I click on the product button the database to be update with the informations which user(id) has order that product(id). First I make orders table with informations(id, product_name, price), other table is users table (id, user_name) and the final table user_order table(id, user_id, order_id);

After that I make two models, one is the Orders model for the products and the second one is the User model. The relationship that I want to make is between this two models.

User model function:

```
public function orders(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders', 'user_order', 'user_id', 'order_id');
       // return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders');
    }
```

Orders model function:

```
public function users(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_order', 'order_id', 'user_id');
        //return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
   }
```

This is the main html where I show all products with the submit button:

```
 <div class="row">
                    @foreach($orders as $order)
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">{{ $order->cena }}</h4>
                                <h4><a href="#">{{ $order->order_name }}</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>See more snippets like this online store item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">15 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group center">

                                <a href="{{ route('product.makeOrder',['id' => $order->id]) }}" name="req" class="btn btn-warning">Order this product!</a> 
                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Controller function:

```
public function makeOrder(Request $request, $id){

        $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->first();
        $findorder = Orders::find($id);
        //$user->orders()->detach();
        $user->orders()->attach(Orders::where('id', $findorder))->first();

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

And the route:

```
Route::get('/add-to-database/{id}',[
        'uses' => 'AppController@makeOrder',
        'as' => 'product.makeOrder'
        ]);
```

The whole idea is how to make function after submiting the button the table user_order to be updated with the id of the user, and id of the product.

Any help?

Comment: What isn't working or which part do you need help with?

Comment: I don't know how to make function that will make this things that I mention in the question

Comment: Have you at least created the route and the controller for this? Also, I can't see a submit button.

Comment: I think that the pivot should be the `order` and the User model should have a `products()` method, and the Product model should have `user()` method. USER has many order and not belong to many order.

Comment: watch this it's free: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

Comment: @RossWilson I have submit button at the bottom od the html and also i update the question with the controller and the route functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `makeOrder()` should be as:

```
public function makeOrder(Request $request, $id) {
  $user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();

  // this is to make sure that order is available in database
  $order = Orders::findOrFail($id);

  $user->orders()->attach($order->id);

  return redirect()->back();
}
```